# Unirest post file with wrong credential fails with RetryExec: I/O exception

Tags: java, html, dropwizard, unirest

I had developed HTML form multipart data request wrapper at server end which reads form-data and calls post API with those data. But Unirest POST API call fails when passing file data with wrong credentials. Using `postman` tool for the same case, it's giving proper response `401 - User Unauthorized`.

Wrapper code:

```
@POST
@Timed
@UnitOfWork
@Path("/add")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public View addFirmwareView(@Context UriInfo uriInfo, @FormDataParam("field1") String field1,
        @FormDataParam("field2") String field2, @FormDataParam("field3") String field3,
        @FormDataParam("file") final InputStream stream,
        @FormDataParam("file") final FormDataContentDisposition contentDisposition,
        @FormDataParam("username") String username, @FormDataParam("password") String password) {

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("field1", field1);
    json.put("field2", field2);
    json.put("field3", field3);
    String jsonFirmware = json.toString();
    String url = BASE_URL + SEPARATOR + FIRMWARE_URL;
    L.info("Add url: {}", url);
    HttpRequest httpRequest = Unirest.post(url)
            .header("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64Coder.encodeString(username + ":" + password))
            .header("cache-control", "no-cache")
            .field("file", stream, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, contentDisposition.getFileName())
            .field("firmware", jsonFirmware).getHttpRequest();
    HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = httpRequest.asString();
    return httpResponse;
}
```

Error logs:

```
web_1               | INFO  [2017-08-31 09:44:15,462] com.firmwareapi.security.BasicAuthenticator: User and Password does not match.
web_1               | 172.17.0.1 - - [31/Aug/2017:09:44:15 +0000] "POST /v1/firmware HTTP/1.1" 401 78 "-" "unirest-java/1.3.11" 4
web_1               | INFO  [2017-08-31 09:44:15,468] org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://192.168.99.100:8080: Broken pipe
web_1               | INFO  [2017-08-31 09:44:15,468] com.firmwareapi.resources.FirmwareViewResource: AddFirmwareView error: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException, class: com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException
web_1               | com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
web_1               |   at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:143)
web_1               |   at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asString(BaseRequest.java:56)
web_1               |   at com.firmwareapi.helper.APIHelper.addFirmware(APIHelper.java:36)
web_1               |   at com.firmwareapi.resources.FirmwareViewResource.addFirmwareView(FirmwareViewResource.java:137)
web_1               |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
web_1               |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
web_1               |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
web_1               |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
web_1               |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
web_1               |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
web_1               |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
web_1               |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
web_1               |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
web_1               |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
web_1               |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
web_1               |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
web_1               |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
web_1               |   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
web_1               |   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
web_1               |   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
web_1               |   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
web_1               |   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
web_1               |   at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
web_1               |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
web_1               |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
web_1               |   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
web_1               |   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
web_1               |   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
web_1               |   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
web_1               |   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
web_1               |   at io.dropwizard.jetty.NonblockingServletHolder.handle(NonblockingServletHolder.java:49)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
web_1               |   at io.dropwizard.servlets.ThreadNameFilter.doFilter(ThreadNameFilter.java:34)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
web_1               |   at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.handle(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:50)
web_1               |   at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.doFilter(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:44)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:541)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1239)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:481)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1141)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
web_1               |   at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:241)
web_1               |   at io.dropwizard.jetty.ContextRoutingHandler.handle(ContextRoutingHandler.java:38)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:494)
web_1               |   at io.dropwizard.jetty.BiDiGzipHandler.handle(BiDiGzipHandler.java:68)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:56)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:169)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:122)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecutingExecutionStrategy.invoke(ExecutingExecutionStrategy.java:58)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:201)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:133)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
web_1               |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
web_1               |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
web_1               | Caused by: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
web_1               |   at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
web_1               |   at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
web_1               |   at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
web_1               |   at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
web_1               |   at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:138)
web_1               |   ... 65 more
web_1               | Caused by: org.apache.http.client.NonRepeatableRequestException: Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity
web_1               |   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:107)
web_1               |   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
web_1               |   at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
web_1               |   ... 69 more
web_1               | Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
web_1               |   at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
web_1               |   at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
web_1               |   at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
web_1               |   at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.streamWrite(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:126)
web_1               |   at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.flushBuffer(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:138)
web_1               |   at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.write(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:169)
web_1               |   at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedOutputStream.flushCacheWithAppend(ChunkedOutputStream.java:124)
web_1               |   at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedOutputStream.write(ChunkedOutputStream.java:181)
web_1               |   at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.InputStreamBody.writeTo(InputStreamBody.java:93)
web_1               |   at org.apache.http.entity.mime.AbstractMultipartForm.doWriteTo(AbstractMultipartForm.java:134)
web_1               |   at org.apache.http.entity.mime.AbstractMultipartForm.writeTo(AbstractMultipartForm.java:157)
web_1               |   at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity.writeTo(MultipartFormEntity.java:103)
web_1               |   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RequestEntityProxy.writeTo(RequestEntityProxy.java:123)
web_1               |   at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:158)
web_1               |   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.sendRequestEntity(CPoolProxy.java:162)
web_1               |   at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:237)
web_1               |   at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:122)
web_1               |   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
web_1               |   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
web_1               |   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
web_1               |   ... 71 more
web_1               | INFO  [2017-08-31 09:44:15,503] org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener: Session Metrics {
web_1               |     85814 nanoseconds spent acquiring 2 JDBC connections;
web_1               |     134982 nanoseconds spent releasing 2 JDBC connections;
web_1               |     0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
web_1               |     0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
web_1               |     0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
web_1               |     0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
web_1               |     0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
web_1               |     0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
web_1               |     0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
web_1               |     0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
web_1               | }
```

I spent a lot of time to figure out this weird issue but won't be able to fix it. If anyone have any possible solution. Please share.